# Clojure vars with metadata

Tags: clojure, metadata

Is it possible to create a new var with metadata without going through an "intermediate" var?

In other words, I know I can do the following:

```
(def a-var 2)
(def another-var (with-meta a-var {:foo :bar}))
```

but is there any way to create `another-var` without creating `a-var` first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
user> (def ^{:foo :bar} another-var 2)
#'user/another-var
user> (clojure.pprint/pprint (meta #'another-var))
{:ns #<Namespace user>,
 :name another-var,
 :file "NO_SOURCE_FILE",
 :line 1,
 :foo :bar}
nil
```

Answer (score 7):

Also note, that `(def another-var (with-meta a-var {:foo :bar}))` does not attach the metadata to the *Var*, but to the *value*. And since in your example `a-var` holds an Integer, I wouldn't expect your example to work at all, since Integers can't hold metadata.

```
user=> (def a-var 2)
#'user/a-var
user=> (def another-var (with-meta a-var {:foo :bar}))
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IObj (NO_SOURCE_FILE:2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize the difference.